# Prefab enemy all walk in same random path

Tags: unity-game-engine, random, instantiation

I have a script on an enemy that walks randomly inside a square. I get a random point from that square and moves the enemy towards that random generated point. 
The problem is that whan instantiating multiple enemies they all run on the same script and uses the same random generated point so they all ends up walking in the same direction.

I think unity only instantiates copies of the prefab not the script so that all prefabs uses the same script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WanderSquare : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Renderer square;
    Vector3 size;
    public int directionChangeInterval;
    static Vector3 direction;
    public float speed;

    void Start()
    {
        size = square.bounds.size;

        StartCoroutine(NewHeading());
    }


    Vector3 NewHeadingRoutine()
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-size.x/2, size.x/2), 0.3f, Random.Range(-size.z/2, size.z/2));

        return position;
    }
    IEnumerator NewHeading()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            direction=NewHeadingRoutine();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(directionChangeInterval);
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,direction,speed/100);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `direction` is a static variable, so every instance of the script is using the same direction.  Whenever a new value of `direction` is calculated, every instance of the script will start using that direction.

Remove the `static` from `direction`, and it should work.

Comment: WOW you are an angle! I almost lost my mind and went crazy. Love coding but i also hate it becouse of stuff like this ahhaha
Chears

Comment: You're welcome.  I can't count the number of times I've spent hours or days trying to figure out a problem, only to realize it was just a little mistake I made.

Comment: Id give up an upvote but i dont have enough reputation ahha

Comment: I always get told I don't have enough reputation too when I try to get into a club.

Comment: And this is why I've left comments on *three different answers* (to different questions) *just yesterday* telling people not to "just make it static"

Comment: Create your own disco in unity with AI and you can be the almighty king!